# Opening a Form from UserControl and pass a Value to Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a small problem, I have `UserControl1` containing a `Button` and a `TextBox`. I've an instance of the user control on `Form1` and I want when I click the button of user control, `Form2` get opened and the text from the textbox of user control appear in `TextBox1` if `Form2`.

NineBerry give me this example [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603960/handle-event-of-a-user-controls-control-in-a-form) but I can't solve the problem yet using the link, any help please :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle event of a User Control's control in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603960/handle-event-of-a-user-controls-control-in-a-form)

Comment: @NineBerry  I cant do it like the example you put it,
how i can do it in textbox text ??

Comment: When do you want to pass text which is in user control to a textbox in the form? Does the form request to read text or does the control should notify the form from changes? Describe it a little more.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks to be here, what i have is, `textbox1` and `Button1` in `UserControl1`, what i want is when i click `button1` in `UserControl1`  `Form2` opened and the text from `textbox1` in `UserControl`  appear in `textbox1` in `form2`,(i have 9 textboxes

Comment: *1)* First you should create an event for your `UserControl` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36130796/3110834). Then in your `Form1` you can subscribe for the event like any other event. **2** For reading value from `textBox1` of user control and setting `textBox1` of your form, the best option is having a property like what I have in example 2 of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834) for `Form2` and `UserControl1`. Then you can simply read value from user control in that event and set the value for the second form. You will find those posts really useful.

Comment: By the way, if always you want to Open `Form2` and pass text of `TextBox1` to it, you don't need to create an consume the event. It's enough to handle `Click` event of `Button1` and then use either of examples 1 to 3 from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei, i solved the problem, thanks again for helping:)

Comment: Great! You're welcome :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how i Don it, Thanks for my Friend  Reza Aghaei for helping.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frm As New SbillPrint
        frm.smoney_txt.Text = moneys_txt.Text
        frm.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: Future readers should know when you put a `TextBox` on a `Form`, it's modifier is `Friend` by default and the control is accessible from other classes and forms, so you can simply access the control using `YourFormInstance.YourTextBox.Text`.